# How to get list the changes between two xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml

Can anyone help me to get the list of difference from two xml files?

XML1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Params>

  <CompanyId Id="Default">

    <SubCompany Id="Default">

        <PULL>
         <DO_CLEANUP>true</DO_CLEANUP>
         <ERROR_FOLDER_RELATIVE>error</ERROR_FOLDER_RELATIVE>
         <DELAY>10</DELAY>
         <MAX_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED>10</MAX_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED>
        </PULL>

         ..... Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....

    </Carrier>

  </SubCompany>

 </Params>
```

XML2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Params>

  <CompanyId Id="Default">

    <SubCompany Id="Default">

        <PULL>
         <DO_CLEANUP>false</DO_CLEANUP>
         <ERROR_FOLDER_RELATIVE>error</ERROR_FOLDER_RELATIVE>
         <DELAY>50</DELAY>
         <MIN_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED>50</MIN_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED>
        </PULL>

         ..... Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....
         ....  Many more node ....

    </SubCompany>

  </CompanyId>

 </Params>
```

I want to get following kind of output

1. DO_CLEANUP node value has been changed from true to false
2. DELAY node value has been changed from 10 to 50
3. MIN_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED node has been newly added with value 50
4. MAX_ATTEMPTS_ALLOWED node has been removed from new file

I have tried with xmlDiff but didn't find correct approach to achieve this.

Comment: You can achieve that by using this [Library](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) Or take a look [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28119e6d-033c-4459-904b-d8cc245cf0a5/i-have-two-xml-documents-identical-in-structure-if-a-element-value-in-a-is-different-than-b-then?forum=csharpgeneral) Or look at microsoft API [XML diff API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

Comment: let me try this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);

            var result1 = doc1.Descendants("PULL").FirstOrDefault()
                .Elements().Select(x => new { tagName = x.Name.LocalName, value = (string)x }).ToList();

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);

            var result2 = doc2.Descendants("PULL").FirstOrDefault()
                .Elements().Select(x => new { tagName = x.Name.LocalName, value = (string)x }).ToList();

            //use left outer join to combine
            var joins =
                (from r1 in result1
                     join r2 in result2 on r1.tagName equals r2.tagName into r
                     from r2 in r.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { tagName = r1.tagName, v1 = (r1 == null) ? null : r1.value, v2 = (r2 == null) ? null : r2.value }
                ).ToList();

            foreach(var join in joins)
            {
                if (join.v1 == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Was deleted in File 1, File 2 value '{1}'", join.tagName, join.v2); 
                    continue;
                }
                if (join.v2 == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Was deleted in File 2, File 1 value '{1}'", join.tagName, join.v1);
                    continue;
                }
                if (join.v1 == join.v2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', is equal in File 1 and File 2, value '{1}'", join.tagName, join.v1);
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', was changed, File 1 value '{1}', File 2 value '{2}'", join.tagName, join.v1, join.v2);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect !!

Comment: There is minor change, can you please edit it, variable value from var result2 = doc1 to var result2 = doc2

Comment: I fixed code and also fixed cases where null occurred.